# Tick Traits library, How To declare Tick class as friend

Tags: c++17, type-traits

How to declare tick class as friend of another class.

Tick library here
https://github.com/pfultz2/Tick

```
example
`TICK_TRAIT(My_Trait)
{
    template<class T_SomeType>
    auto require(T&& x) -> valid<
        decltype(T_SomeType::SomeFunc()) 
    >;
};`
class SomeClass{

private:
friend My_Trait<SomeClass>;
SomeFunc(){}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `class` keyword to your friend declaration:

`friend class My_Trait<SomeClass>;`